# How to cleanly wire this improvised power socket?

Tags: electrical

DIY community!

On one of my walls there was a cable running to provide a socket across the room. This cable was interrupted in the middle, and a socket was added there. Since this required some extra wire, looks like the missing bit was added after the socket, and it doesn't look very clean:

[image: Image of socket with added wire]

What is a good way to make this clean? Do  I need to replace the whole cable?

PS. The black part contains a wago connector, so at least it is safe

---

Great solution ! Solved :

[image]

Comment: "at least it is safe" for some values of "safe". There's a reason you don't see wiring like that everywhere - it's really not all that safe.

Comment: Nicely done, though I'd suggest tightening up the line feeding out of the single socket just a bit so it doesn't have the loop sagging over the base board. That's a purely cosmetic fix, though, and isn't required for safety or reliability. I suppose there's a possibility that little loop could get caught by something and yanked out...

Comment: @FreeMan Good point, I didn't consider the possibility of the loop getting caught. The loop happened because I chose to cut the cable too long rather than too short.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add another receptacle around a foot or so past the splice. Cut the existing cable before the splice and wire it to the new receptacle. Add a new section of cable between the two receptacles.

Comment: Or if you'd find one more convenient a bit further along, and don't mind buying a bit more cable to do that, you can put it anywhere in that direction.

Comment: Solved (see edit). Thank you for the nice idea!